# Should a post lacking tzenius be deleted immediately it appears?

Tags: discussion, deletions, modesty-policy

I just now voted to delete this question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35982/ which seems to me to be **obviously** out-of-place on this site. The Help Centre says "Please respect that in the Jewish tradition certain questions, especially certain questions relating to sexuality, are discussed only in private. Such questions will be closed or deleted at the discretion of the moderators or community." 
Am I wrong in thinking this should have been "deleted at the discretion of the moderators" when it appeared on the grounds of

irrelevant to Judaism (quotes non-Jewish sources) but more importantly

lacking tznius

(and just possibly seeking to give the site a bad name)?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you are wrong but I also don't think you are right. There is no clear line where mods know to act quickly to delete. It has happened before that questions have been deleted on the spot (and you probably haven't even noticed). If you feel a certain post should be deleted when it hasn't you should vote to delete if possible and/or flag for a moderator to do so. We value your input in making decisions!

Answer (score 2):

If the post is obviously trolling or a baited question I think it should be but if it lacks tzenuis and is actually just a poorly worded question a mod should be able to edit it or hide it until the poster rewords it.

Just my opinion, fwiw

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, and welcome to meta.  One note: *anybody* who sees a fixable problem in a post is free to edit (or propose an edit, if you don't have enough rep yet to directly edit).  The site is improved by the whole community, not just the mods.  Besides, there are a lot more of you than us, so from a simple efficiency angle, don't wait for us!